# Seasonal adjustment line chart - Orange data mining

Tags: orange

I'm trying to create a Seasonality plot in Orange data mining but it doesn't seem to plot the calculations.  I don't get error messages and the supplied data set shows up on the line chart.

Workflow:

File, data table, As timeseries, seasonality, Line chart

My dataset is just has two fields:

Name - Date, Type - datetime, Role - feature
Name - Requests, Type - numeric, Role - target

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the Seasonal Adjustment widget, it is not meant to show any plot. It computes seasonal adjustment of the given series and returns a data table. Use Line Chart to plot the data. Make sure you are using the latest version of the Timeseries add-on.